# Node orm2 query to search for a partial string in two columns?

Tags: node.js, orm

I am able to search one column for my partial string, but I want to search the columns `bottom` and `top`. My route...

```
.get('/admin/search/tablename/string/:string', (req, res) => {
  const searchString = req.params.string;
  req.models.tablename.find().where('bottom LIKE ?', [`%${searchString}%`]).run((err, results) => {
    res.send(results);
  });
});
```

The above works well for matching those characters in the `bottom` column. But I need to find thats string in both the `bottom` and the `top` columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get the results I wanted by adding an OR condition like below.

```
.get('/admin/search/tablename/string/:string', (req, res) => {
  const searchString = req.params.string;
  req.models.tablename.find().where(
    'bottom LIKE ? OR top LIKE ?',     
    [`%${searchString}%`,`%${searchString}%`]).run((err, results) => {
      res.send(results);
    });
});
```